# TWRP is stuck at the boot screen when trying to flash twrp on Mi A2

Tags: rooting, twrp, fastboot, boot, mi-a2

I am trying to root my Mi A2 android phone. I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSziEe_k3HM) tutorial. When I try fastboot boot path/to/twrp/image the phone gets stuck on the boot screen. What am I doing wrong?

Is it because a) I don't have required drivers or because b) I have to disable force encryption? If a) I have to install new drivers what are they, where do I get them and how do I install them? If it is b) about disabling force encryption then how to do it?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the command-line text output you get after executing the fastboot command.

Answer (score 2):

The twrp-3.3.1-0 works for me, so download the twrp-3.3.1-0-jasmine_sprout.img and twrp-installer-3.3.1-0-jasmine_sprout.zip from [here](https://eu.dl.twrp.me/jasmine_sprout/) and issue the following commands on fastboot/bootloader mode

```
fastboot set_active b
fastboot flash boot twrp-3.3.1-0-jasmine_sprout.img
fastboot reboot recovery
```

or just

```
fastboot boot twrp-3.3.1-0-jasmine_sprout.img
```

enable side-loading mode in advance options in twrp recovery mode and issue

```
adb sideload twrp-installer-3.3.1-0-jasmine_sprout.zip
```

and download Disable_Dm-Verity_ForceEncrypt_03.04.2020.zip from [here](https://zackptg5.com/downloads/Disable_Dm-Verity_ForceEncrypt_11.02.2020.zip) and get Magisk-v21.0.zip and MagiskManager-v8.0.0.apk from [here](https://magisk.me/) or [here](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases)
and then in twrp recovery mode, select Wipe->format Data and select partition 'a' on reboot tab on twrp menu but do not reboot. Now activate sideload from advance menu and issue

```
adb sideload Disable_Dm-Verity_ForceEncrypt_03.04.2020.zip
adb sideload Magisk-v21.0.zip
```

and then rebooting into system should enable root on your phone. I used this [link](https://magisk.me/root-mi-a2-a2-lite-magisk-install-twrp-recovery/) for the answer. Also you can look into these links,
[link1](https://www.thecustomdroid.com/xiaomi-mi-a2-lite-android-10-update/),
[link2](https://www.thecustomdroid.com/root-xiaomi-mi-a2-a2-lite-android-pie-magisk/) and
[link3](https://miui.blog/mi-a2/guide-flash-twrp-xiaomi-mi-a2/).

Comment: Also you can gain root adb shell from your host machine like this `adb root` and then `adb remount` to remount the system partition with write permissions and copy the su binaries into /system/bin/ and also you can get into a root shell on your phone from host machine by issuing `adb root` and then `adb shell`. *(Perhaps this feature works on LineageOS only for if `rooted debugging` is checked or may be in some other custom roms)*
Or you can directly use Magisk patched boot image for **MI_A2** to flash to boot from [here](https://miui.blog/mi-a2/stock-patched-boot-image-files-mi-a2/)

Comment: It works with [LineageOS 17.1 unofficial rom](https://github.com/LineageOS-MI-A2-MI-6X/LineageOS-OTA/releases) , magisk succeeds in rooting the device using [this method](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-ota-10-x-lineageos-17-1-unofficial-jasmine_sprout-mi-a2.3966643/).

Answer (score 1):

A low or dead battery can cause this issue. Before flashing always make sure the phones battery is at least 70%